# C# 4.5 Setting property

Tags: c#, settings

I would like to ensure that a setting exist (C# 4.5). The following code does not bring any error if the setting ('CompteDefautFactureF' in my case) already exists. However, things are getting a little bit messy and I get an error if no entry in the user.xml file is found.

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.CompteDefautFactureF != "")
                {
                    foreach (ClsCompte l_Account in this.cbo_Compte_FF.Items)
                    {
                        if (l_Account.ID == Properties.Settings.Default.CompteDefautFactureF)
                        {
                            this.cbo_Compte_FF.SelectedItem = l_Account;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.cbo_Compte_FF.SelectedItem = null;
                }
```

This is the contents of my user.xml file (i.e. all the settings previously saved):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <Finapp2013.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="CopyOperationStatus" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="TransferScheduledOperations" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="TransferScheduledOperationsDaysInAdvance" serializeAs="String">
                <value>3</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MonnaieBase" serializeAs="String">
                <value>CHF</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="OpenExchangeRatesID" serializeAs="String">
                <value>abcde</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="NumberOfDecimalsCalculator" serializeAs="String">
                <value>18</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="AffichageSituationPatrimonialeToutesOp" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="DisplayScheduledOperationsDaysInAdvance" serializeAs="String">
                <value>5</value>
            </setting>
        </Finapp2013.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

How can I solve this problem properly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my way by writing a method as follows :

```
    public static bool doesSettingExist(string pSettingName)
    {
        List<string> l_Settings = null;
        string l_Value = string.Empty;
        bool l_Return = false;

        try
        {
            // initialises the new list
            l_Settings = new List<string>();

            // feeds the list dictionary
            foreach (SettingsProperty currentProperty in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
            {
                if (Properties.Settings.Default[currentProperty.Name] != null)
                {
                    l_Settings.Add(currentProperty.Name);
                }
            }

            if (l_Settings.Contains(pSettingName))
            {
                l_Return = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ClsErrorManager.manageException(exc);
        }

        finally
        {
        }

        return l_Return;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default["CompteDefautFactureF"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    foreach (ClsCompte l_Account in this.cbo_Compte_FF.Items)
                    {
                        if (l_Account.ID.ToString().Equals( Properties.Settings.Default["CompteDefautFactureF"].ToString()))
                        {
                            this.cbo_Compte_FF.SelectedItem = l_Account;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.cbo_Compte_FF.SelectedItem = null;
                }
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm still getting the same error as the setting is not set yet in my user.xml file